# Laravel: Correct way to count items in a shopping basket / many to many relationship

Tags: laravel, many-to-many

I'm working on one of my first Laravel apps. It includes a shopping basket.

At present, I have a model called `Order` and a model called `Product` which both have many to many relationships with each other (`belongsToMany` each way).

As I add items to the order, they are duplicated:

```
// Returned with:
// $order = Order::with('User','Products')->find($id);
// return $order;

{  
    "id":1,
    "user_id":1,
    "notes":"This is a test order",
    "order_type":0,
    "user":{  
        "id":1,
        "first_name":"Dave",
        "created_at":"2014-11-05 15:23:50",
        "updated_at":"2014-11-05 15:23:50"
    },
    "products":[  
        {  
            "id":1,
            "name":"Cheese Wotsits",
            "pivot":{  
                "order_id":1,
                "product_id":1
            }
        },
        {  
            "id":1,
            "name":"Cheese Wotsits",
            "pivot":{  
                "order_id":1,
                "product_id":1
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

How would I go about amending the above to something along the lines of:

```
    ...
    "products":[  
        {  
            "id":1,
            "name":"Cheese Wotsits",
            "count":2,
            "pivot":{  
                "order_id":1,
                "product_id":1
            }
        },
    ]
    ...
```

Should I be adding a count to the pivot table? Or just let Laravel do its thing and count the data at the other end? Or, hopefully, is there a *laravelly* way of doing this?!

Comment: I don't know any way to this natively with Laravel, but what you could is what you said. Add a count to the pivot table, Seems to be the simplest way, maybe not the cleanest. Then if you want to get the count, add withPivot method at the end of your return method in your relation method inside your model. Also, I think you won't be able to add duplicated relation in your pivot table.

Comment: Add a count to your pivot table. When adding a product to the Order, check if the product already exists, and increase the quantity appropriately.

Comment: Another vote for the count here. I think its definitely a better design than having the same pivot table record multiple times. Also to consider: if you have some kind of count in your basket that the user can easily increase / decrease, it is much nicer to just modify a counter in the db instead of adding and removing rows